# the amount of different lines by using jsdifflib

Tags: javascript

In my code, I need to know the amount of the different lines by using "jsdifflib", and how to get the actual number?     "jsdifflib":https://github.com/cemerick/jsdifflib

Comment: It helps to show some code you have already written to show us where you have gotten to with your problem. With javascript questions linking to a jsfiddle with mostly working code will also greatly increase the odds of your question being answered.

Comment: I only want to know how many rows are different